# Why dig NS returns nothing for a domain while it can find an A record for that domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dns-zone

I'm confused by the DNS resolution. How is it possible that for a domain we can get an IP (A record) but no authoritative NS is returned for that domain. For example

```
dig ns HDRedirect-LB3-890977680.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

returns nothing but

```
dig A HDRedirect-LB3-890977680.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

returns

```
HDRedirect-LB3-890977680.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 51 IN A 52.204.129.22
HDRedirect-LB3-890977680.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 51 IN A 54.85.127.70
```

If the domain can be resolved, it should have an authoritative NS, how can I get that?

Comment: domain (subdman) and hostname in DNS-tree are different entites wth different properties. Lame "subdomain" usage for any FQDN is direct road to Hell. U wanna RTFM or re-read @hakan again and again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works as expected. The incorrect assumption here is that all names should have `NS` records.

Instead, the set of nameservers is defined on a per zone basis, with `NS` records at the zone apex only.

Eg, if you have `example.com` and have not delegated any subdomains elsewhere, then there are no further `NS` records anywhere under example.com.
If you delegate `foo.bar.example.com` elsewhere, then that name (by definition the start of a new zone) will have `NS` records.

There are several possible approaches for finding which zone a given name is part of. It's actually generally a two-step process.

One approach would be to start out with eg:

```
dig HDRedirect-LB3-890977680.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com NS
```

The idea here is that if this name happens to be the apex of a zone (something which you cannot generally know in advance) you get the response that you want.
If it is not the zone apex, you will get a negative response (as there are no `NS` records in that case), but that negative response includes the zone's `SOA` in the `AUTHORITY` section. That `SOA` record will actually tell you where the apex is.

In this case

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. 32 IN      SOA     ns-1119.awsdns-11.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 60
```

So the owner name (left-most column) of the `SOA` record tells you where the zone starts.

Ie, `dig us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. NS` will give you the relevant nameservers.

Another approach would be to follow the chain of delegations (eg `dig +trace`) but in the end that ends up being a case of remembering the last delegation point you saw. Also, if you take this approach and use `dig +trace` specifically, do keep in mind that the output of `dig +trace` by default is very limited and does not really distinguish between the `NS` records from `AUTHORITY` sections when it gets a referral from a parent zone compared to an `NS` record in the `ANSWER` section from the actual authoritative nameserver. 
(You may want to add `+all` to actually see clearly what is happening.)
In the end, if you only saw the referral (with `NS` records in the `AUTHORITY` section) and want to be sure you have the `NS` records that the authoritative server says, you will have to re-query for that particular name.

Comment: Bravissimo!!! First *really good* hostmaster on SF after a long time, which don't mix hostname and subdomain. **I applaud you, sir!!!**

Answer (score -2):

dig us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com should return the SOA for that sub-domain.

what you are asking with "dig ns" is if the host is a NS record or rather what is the ns for that host/domain. the soa does not necessarily point to the NS server for that domain. in fact i thend to think it rarely does. it mostly points to the www host most of the time.

the ns is the nameserver so the dns that answer for the domain the soa is who responds when the domain is looked up  ( the ip address for the whole domain)

ex:

## dig SOA svdx.net +noall +answer

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.13-Ubuntu <<>> SOA svdx.net +noall +answer
;; global options: +cmd
svdx.net.       119 IN  SOA ns2.dnsexit.com. admin.netdorm.com. 2000060701 604800 2400 1814400 1200 <<<<<<<< ns entries.

## dig NS svdx.net +noall +answer

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.13-Ubuntu <<>> NS svdx.net +noall +answer
;; global options: +cmd
svdx.net.       119 IN  NS  ns3.dnsexit.com.
svdx.net.       119 IN  NS  ns4.dnsexit.com.
svdx.net.       119 IN  NS  ns1.dnsexit.com.
svdx.net.       119 IN  NS  ns2.dnsexit.com.

## dig svdx.net

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.13-Ubuntu <<>> svdx.net
;; global options: +cmd

;; ANSWER SECTION:
svdx.net.       119 IN  A   192.0.225.94 <<<<<<<<  not the ns

;; Query time: 78 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Fri Mar 17 03:39:27 EDT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 53